# JE Need Expression

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I am a beginner in the Assembly Language and I've been stuck in this problem

the Assembler tells me that JE needs an expression, but its already there:

Here's my code

```
ag:cmp Byte PTR [Di],"$"
   JE DONE:
     cmp Byte PTR [Si], "$"
     JE DONE:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the ':' after 'DONE'.
Text before a ':' is treated as a label, and as such, the JE instruction cannot find the target label.

Remove the ':'s after DONE to fix the issue.